# "The walk signal lights up" expression

Tags: phrase-usage

When describing the walk signal for pedestrians turning green, can I say:

> The walk signal lights up.

I'm writing this in my college essay to describe a story (anecdote). I'm going to talk about the signal in the US.

Comment: Lot's of such signals are *continuously* "lit up" - either displaying (green) ***Walk*** or (red) ***Don't Walk***. Personally, I'd probably say *The walk signal **came on*** (it switched to the "on" state), which for some reason doesn't clash so much with implied simultaneous *The 'Don't Walk' signal **went off*** (ceased to be displayed; switched to the 'off' state).

Comment: The signal is quite different in the US and elsewhere.  Please specify a dialect.  Also can you provide a context.  Why and to whom would you say this?

Comment: I'm writing this in my college essay to describe a story (anecdote). I'm gonna talk about the signal in the US!

Comment: I have edited that piece of information into your question. For future reference, please provide as much detail as possible in your questions.